# Cannot create secondary x-axis with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to generate a chart with a secondary x-axis, but I can't get the secondary x-axis to be added to the chart.

Below is the code I'm using. If I change "x2_axis" to "y2_axis" and "set_x2_axis" to "set_y2_axis", then I am able to create a secondary y axis successfully -- but it does not work for a secondary x axis. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10],
    [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
    [200,200,100,100,300,300,250,250,350,350]
]
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])
worksheet.write_column('D2', data[3])

chart= workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.add_series ({
    'name': 'Primary',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6',
})
chart.add_series ({
    'name': 'Secondary',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$11',
    'x2_axis': True
})

chart.set_x_axis({
    'name': 'Primary Axis',
    'interval_unit': 1,
    'interval_tick': 1,
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    })
chart.set_y_axis({
    'name': 'Value',
    })
chart.set_x2_axis({
    'label_position': 'low',
    'name': 'Secondary Axis',
    'visible': True
    })
worksheet.insert_chart('B20', chart)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a secondary X axis in Excel (or XlsxWriter) isn't obvious, in comparison to setting a secondary Y axis. Generally, you need to add a secondary Y and X axis **pair** before you can set a secondary X axis. Something like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
    [200, 200, 100, 100, 300, 300, 250, 250, 350, 350]
]

worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])
worksheet.write_column('D2', data[3])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.add_series({
    'name': 'Primary',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6',
})

chart.add_series({
    'name': 'Secondary',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$11',
    'x2_axis': True,
    'y2_axis': True,
})

chart.set_x_axis({
    'name': 'Primary Axis',
    'interval_unit': 1,
    'interval_tick': 1,
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    })

chart.set_y_axis({
    'name': 'Y Values 1',
    })

chart.set_y2_axis({
    'name': 'Y Values 2',
    'crossing': 'max',
    })

chart.set_x2_axis({
    'label_position': 'high',
    'name': 'Secondary Axis',
    'visible': True,
    })

worksheet.insert_chart('B20', chart)
workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for helping me out so quickly!